# How to send code, pressing a button and receiving output of a website?

Tags: python, python-requests

Sorry if the title is not clear enough, English is not my main language and I have trouble writing technical stuff.

There's this website:
https://www.cleancss.com/javascript-obfuscate/index.php

I need to be able to send code to this website obfuscating input and to receive its output. I have NO idea how to to this. I was thinking on using web browser module but I'd prefer that this is done in the background, so no explorer window is opened.

Please help me approach a solution for this!

Comment: you can use Selenium library to interact with website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obfuscated code is inside the `textarea` with id `packed`.

Javascript obfuscate API

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('file.js') as s:
    source= s.read()
cookies = {
    'PHPSESSID': 'foln2l1v1564o66vmbs19mk0j1',
}

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Origin': 'https://www.cleancss.com',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
    'Referer': 'https://www.cleancss.com/javascript-obfuscate/index.php',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,ta;q=0.8',
}

data = {
  'ascii_encoding': '62^',
  'fast_decode': 'on^',
  'src': source
}

response = requests.post('https://www.cleancss.com/javascript-obfuscate/index.php', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data)


soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')
with open('file2.js') as f:
    print(soup.select('#packed')[0].text,file=f)
```